# How to deploy an ascync telegram bot that periodically requests api and responds to users at the same time (does two tasks simultaneously))

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, aiohttp, aiogram

This is my first question on Stack so please don't judge me if I do something wrong. I'm also new to developing a telegram bot.

I'm making an async telegram bot with aiogram library that has the following workflow:

1. Every hour it does a huge request to some api and stores received data in Heroku PostgreSQL
2. It also sends all users some info from the responses gathered
3. **At the same time** the bot should be ready to reply to users at all times. For now, it is simply echoing incoming messages

You can check out the whole code in this [repo](https://github.com/dushamishkin/crypto-arbitrage-tgbot). I'll try my best to **explain the structure below: **

*utils/db.py* describes a class that connects to a database and inserts a row in it using `insert_row()`:

```
class BotDB:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db_connection = psycopg2.connect(db, sslmode='require')
        self.db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()

    def insert_row(self, row):
        self.db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO events(timestamp, pair, sell_at, buy_at, sell_price_bid, buy_price_ask, sell_volume, buy_volume, profit) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        self.db_cursor.commit()
```

*utils/parser_v3.py* describes a class that asynchronously sends around 120 requests to the api and gets responses using `get_pair()` and `execute_tasks()`. After that it inserts all rows into the database, as it inherits from BotDB class. The most interesting parts are the `boot_up()` and `run_periodically()` functions that implement [Periodic library](https://github.com/vd2org/periodic) to get requests periodically:

```
async def boot_up(self):
    p = Periodic(self.interval, self.execute_tasks, self.pairs)
    await p.start()

def run_periodically(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(self.boot_up())
    loop.run_forever()
```

*main.py* - I believe this is the place where it all goes wrong, because I can't really understand how the async webhooking function and my async function can work together. I also suspect that the problem lies within the event loop I created in `run_periodically()`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    start_webhook(
    dispatcher=dp,
    webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
    skip_updates=True,
    on_startup=on_startup,
    on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
    host=WEBAPP_HOST,
    port=WEBAPP_PORT,
)
    print('WEBHOOKED')
    parser.run_periodically()
    print('RAN 1 TIME, HOPE IT WORKS')
```

**Results after deploying to Heroku:**

1. The bot is successfully echoing user
2. But it doesn't start the `run_periodically()` function, see Heroku logs below:

> WEBHOOKED # This means the first function in main.py succeeds
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/app/main.py", line 67, in
>
> parser.run_periodically()
>
> File "/app/utils/parser_v3.py", line 58, in run_periodically
>
> loop.create_task(self.boot_up())
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line
> 436, in create_task
>
> self._check_closed()
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line
> 515, in _check_closed
>
> raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
>
> RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
>
> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Parser.boot_up' was never awaited

I can't understand why `boot_up()` was never awaited. I believe I've put all the necessary `await` keywords.

If anybody knows how to fix this **or** knows a better solution for my project please help!

Comment: I'd use a second script, why make thinks over complicated? A single script that will read a DB and response to users, and another script that will get the data every x minutus and push it to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I see your point and I was indeed thinking about this solution. But here is the catch. For example you have scripts 1 and 2. Script 1 is parsing and saving to DB. Script 2 is the telegram bot which replies to messages. How are you going to make Script 2 post responses from Script 1 every hour.